# Different text used of sorting and filtering

Tags: tablesorter

in a app,  I use jQueryTablesorter, and the widget https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html

I have two main features :
- filtering (the widget)
- sorting (default feature)

Both of these feature use `textExtraction()` function,

https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textextraction

My problem is the following :

- for sorting, I would like to use computer form of a date, that is "2020-04-01"
- for  filtering, I would like to use human form (in French "1er avril 2020").

How can I deal with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found. I need to use a hook which modify the value parsed for filtering.

```
$.tablesorter.filter.types.start = function(config, data) {
       data.exact = data.$cells[data.index];
       data.exact = data.exact.innerText;
       data.iExact = data.exact.toLowerCase();
       return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a date library like sugar or date.js - check out this demo: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-dates.html. What that library does is use the parser to convert the filter into a normalized date that will match with the date in the column. You would also need to add a `filter-parsed` class name to the column ([ref](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html#classes)).

Comment: unfortuatly, I am afraid a date parser won't be useful, as my cells can contains both date and the title of the events. More generally, I would prefer to have distinct text fo sorting and filtering (especillay because I can't determine today which data type I will need in the feature)